# The SI-unit of the cosmological constant (vacuum energy) is $\frac{1}{m^2}$. What does that have to do with Energy?

Tags: energy, dimensional-analysis, density, si-units, cosmological-constant

I just don't get how Energy is measured in $\frac{1}{m^2}$. Wasn't it measured in Joules? (source is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant#Equation)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @KDP, Look at e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant#Equation, there is a numerical value with units of m^{-2}

Comment: You really want an energy _density_, proportional to $\Lambda c^4/G$.

Comment: The source you gave in your comment gives a value for the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ in units of $m^{-2}$. This is *not* directly a measurement of energy (although it is closely related to the vacuum energy).

Answer (score 3):

The cosmological constant $\Lambda$ appears in the Einstein equations as
$$G_{\mu\nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi G T_{\mu\nu}$$
Just to be clear, this is in units where $c=1$ so any units of time and mass can be expressed in terms of units of length and energy, respectively. Now I'll write the units of everything in terms of an energy scale $E$ (e.g. Joules), and a length scale $L$ (e.g. meters):

$T$ is an energy-density with units $EL^{-3}$.

$G$ is Newton's gravitational constant with SI units of $J*m*kg^{-2}$, or upon setting $c=1$, units of $LE^{-1}$. So $GT$ has units of $L^{-2}$.

On the left side, the metric $g$ is dimensionless, so to be consistent with $GT$ on the right side, $\Lambda$ must have dimensions of $L^{-2}$, and that's why the numerical value of $\Lambda$ is indeed expressed in $m^{-2}$

When the cosmological constant is referred to as an "vacuum energy", it should really be understood as vacuum energy *density*, like $T$. And it involves moving $\Lambda g$ to the right side of the equation and factoring out $G$, which as you see above really does give you units of energy-density.

Answer (score 2):

The Einstein field equations are
$$G_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu}$$
where the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ has dimension length$^{-2}$, and
the gravitational constant $\kappa=8\pi G/c^4$ has dimension energy$^{-1}\cdot$length.

We can bring the cosmological term from the left to the right side
of the equation.
$$G_{\mu\nu}=\kappa \left(T_{\mu\nu} - \frac{\Lambda}{\kappa}g_{\mu\nu}\right)$$

And by defining $\Lambda=\kappa\ \rho_\text{vac}$ this becomes
$$G_{\mu\nu}=\kappa \left(T_{\mu\nu} - \rho_\text{vac}\  g_{\mu\nu}\right)$$

Thus $\rho_\text{vac}$ has the dimension energy$\cdot$length$^{-3}$
and can be interpreted as a vacuum energy density.

So cosmological constant $\Lambda$ and vacuum density $\rho_\text{vac}$
are essentially the same thing, only differing by the factor $\kappa$.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the source where you are seeing this value for the cosmological constant. AFAIK, it has a value of approximately $5×10^{-10} J/m^3$, which reduces to units of $[mass] [length]^{-1} [time]^{-2}$, not $[length]^{-2}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant#Equation